# How to store and display formatted text in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get into mobile app development and chose to make a song book app in flutter as my first exercise project. In this app I would like to display the song texts/lyrics as formatted text with paragraphs indentations etc.

My first plan was to store the songs in a (SQLite) database and put in the formatted texts as html code.

However, I noticed that flutter does not really have a built-in html interpreter. I tried some 3rd party plugins but they already failed with simple tables. Now I am considering to use WebView. However, I guess I would then have to store all the song texts as individual htm(l) files.

Does anyone have a recommendation or does someone see an easier way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: What problems did you come across exactly, I will adjust my answer if need be.

Comment: I tried flutter_html but it handles tables in a strange way. It maximizes the column width by using all available space and makes all the columns equally wide. Attributes like width="30" are being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the exactly went wrong with your initial approach, my inclination is that you are on the right track.

sqfLite should work perfectly well for this https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite, then you could use a package like flutter_html https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html to render the html strings or just use RichText class if you want more styling options https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html.